# 3D model viewers

Tags: applications

I would like to be able to view 3D models on my phone. Are there any 3D viewers out there, free or paid, that will allow me to open up a 3D geometry file  and rotate around, zoom, and pan about a 3D model? It doesn't matter what file type, you can always convert them from a computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What abaout http://www.appbrain.com/app/andar-model-viewer/edu.dhbw.andarmodelviewer

also

http://www.appbrain.com/app/model-loader-3d-lite/com.okean.modelloader3dlite

This Was Let Me appBrain search for you
http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=3d+model

Comment: I found the first app on my searches previously, though it was not what i was looking for. My searches did not yield the second app. The second one is almost perfect, thank you.